# React useEffect hook, determine which dependency changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having an issue with the `useEffect` hook where I would only like a conditional statement inside the callback to execute if, and only if, a specific dependency was changed. For example:

```js
const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(3);
const [dep, setDep] = React.useState(1);
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (index === 0) {
    if (dep triggered the callback and not index) {
       setIndex(dep);
    }
  }
}, [index, dep]);

setIndex(0); // I do not want `setIndex(dep)` to execute yet
setDep(5);   // Now, I want `setIndex(dep)` to execute
```

How would I achieve this logic in React? Do I need to use a different hook?

Comment: Have a separate `useEffect` with only `[dep]` as dependencies?

Comment: @jonrsharpe believe me, I have been trying all kinds of obscure hacks including that

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(3);
const [dep, setDep] = React.useState(1);
const [flag,setFlag] = useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  setIndex(0);
  setFlag(true)
}, [dep]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (index === 0 && flag == true) {
    if (dep triggered the callback and not index) {
        setIndex(dep);
    }
  }
  setFlag(false)
}, [flag]);

setIndex(0); // I do not want `setIndex(dep)` to execute yet
setDep(5);
```

Comment: That won't work because your second `useEffect` hook references `dep` and must be required in the dependency array

Comment: what about the if statement that is not valid typescript? that should be removed, right?

Comment: The if will work only when the first useEffect will run.
So the dep will triget the if like the text you wrote inside the if.

Comment: also, i would still need to include `index` and `dep` as dependencies in your second `useEffect` hook because they are referenced in the callback

Comment: no,because you want to triget the sec useEffect only when dep updated. so the flag state will be true only when this first useEffect will run .
index === 0 && flag == true -> only if flag equle true, than the if statmante will run.